# How to pass a variable to a layout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I have a two versions of my application layout, which are differs only in a few lines. Consider following example:

```
!!!    
%html
    %head
        # a lot of code here
%body
    # some more code here
    - if defined? flag and flag == true
        # variant 1
    - else
        # variant 2
```

The question is, how do I pass this flag to the layout?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout 'layout', :locals => {:flag => true} #won't work :(

    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A controller instance variable? That's the normal way to get information to the template.

Comment: Don't use "flag" --- use "@flag"

Comment: How are you attempting to set the variable? *Edit* What Jesse said. Without knowing the rest of what you're doing we kind of have to guess about what the problem might be.

Comment: @Dave check out updated example. I just want to pass a variable (flag) from the controller to the layout.

Comment: I don't think you can pass locals to a layout like that; `layout` only has `:only` and `:except` options (that I'm aware of, anyway). Without knowing what the nature of the conditions are it's hard to give general-purpose advice--there might be a better way.

Comment: If there are several variables to pass, it might be convenient to bundle them in a hash or object which could be reused across all methods requiring that layout.

Answer (score 18):

I usually prefer to use helper methods instead of instance variables in these situations. Here is an example of how it could be done:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'layout'
  helper_method :flag

  ...

protected
  def flag
    true
  end
end
```

And if you have a controller where flag should not be true then you just overwrite the method:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...

private
  def flag
    false # or perhaps do some conditional
  end
end
```

This way you make sure that the flag helper is always available in views so you don't have to do the `if defined?` or anything and also, in the cases where no layout is used, then no instance variable is assigned in any `before_filter`.

It also helps keep as few instance variables as possible in the views.

Comment: How you can use this in only some actions?
For example, I want to make it 'false' only on the 'Index' action.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to write `params[:action] != 'index'` inside the method

Comment: Building on DanneManne's answer, but there is an available helper named `action_name` that you can use. So `action_name != 'index'` would work too. (This, along with `controller_name` are both provided by rails)

Comment: There are also [helper modules](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html)

Answer (score 13):

Okay, so I found the solution by myself:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout 'layout'
    before_filter :set_constants

    def set_constants
        @flag = true
    end
end
```

And the template should be:

```
!!!    
%html
    %head
        # a lot of code here
%body
    # some more code here
    - if @flag
        # variant 1
    - else
        # variant 2
```

Comment: Instead of `if defined? flag and flag == true` just say `if @lite`

Comment: That's what I said, use a controller instance variable. Not sure that's "by yourself," although I'm glad it's working.

Comment: @Dave, you're right, thanks. I'm new to ruby and it take some time to me to find what does it actually means, unfortunately, google doesn't bring a clear explanation to the first results.

Comment: If anybody is wondering what `before_filter` is... same as `before_action`. 

The before_filter syntax is deprecated in Rails 5.0 and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Answer (score 9):

**There is two another option** to do, what actually the OP asked:

#### #1

in your layout:

```
- if flag ||= false
  # variant 1
- else
  # variant 2
```

in your application controller (this is the trick):

```
layout 'application' # or whatever
```

in any kind of controller:

```
render :locals => { :flag => true }
```

My guess would be, the layout processing is happening later cause of the "dynamic" (not really) `layout` definition and that generates the necessary methods for all the keys inside of `local_assigns`. So maybe the instance variable is a performanter solution. Any thoughts about that? Please leave a comment.

#### #2

You could just use the `local_assigns` variable like:

```
- if local_assigns[:flag] ||= false
  # variant 1
- else
  # variant 2
```

and then in any of your controller:

```
render :locals => { :flag => true }
```

Answer (score -1):

What about this http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/236 in order to conditionally select layouts?