# In Rails, can I lookup a relation without explicitly looking it up in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-keys, relation

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  In my model, my user has an attribute, “avatar_file_id” which links to a table in which the filename is defined.  The “avatar_files” table has the fields

```
id
file
```

When the user is logged in, I want to display the avatar image on my page, but I’m having trouble figuring out how.  In my controller, I have a reference to the logged in user (@current_user), and so I have

```
                <%= image_tag "avatar_images/#{current_user.avatar_file_id}", alt: current_user.name %>
```

but clearly, this will only attempt to lookup a file where the filename is the id, which is not how things are setup.  Do I need to explictly lookup the image file in my controller and then include that variable on the page or is there some slicker way of getting the image path given only the user object?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Which field holds the avatar image?

Comment: It is the avatar_file.file that has the actual path.  The user model has an avatar_file_id that links to this table.

Comment: Try `<%= image_tag current_user.avatar_file.file, alt: current_user.name %>`

Comment: I get the error "undefined method `avatar_file' for #<User:0x007fc041508bc0>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<%= image_tag "avatar_images/#{Avatar.find(current_user.avatar_file_id).file}", alt: current_user.name %>
```

But you skip a lot of safeguards to do it this way (i.e. what if a user hasn't uploaded an avatar image?) and if you put that sort of stuff in your view things really start to get messy.

Generally you want as little logic in your views as possible since it's much harder debug html/Ruby than the pure Ruby in your controller so it's probably better just to load the object in your controller and pass it through in a variable.

Comment: I see your point but this code is part of my "./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb", which gets rendered by many controller methods.  Are you sayhing I need to come up with foolproof logic and then put it in each method that will end up rendering the above page?

Comment: I'm saying there might be a better way to do it, but personally, I'd just make it work at first and refactor later. It wont make any difference to the end user

Comment: "there might be a better way to do it", I know that is also what I said in my question in so many words ("is there some slicker way of getting the image path").  I'm looking for that better way as an answer here.

Comment: You asked for a way to get the image given only the user, I gave you that. Third answer down in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382496/how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-layout) should give a way to set variables that will be loaded into all your layouts. You could make the avatar a field within current_user since it's a one-to-one relationship anyway

Comment: Ah, that was just what I was looking for.  Thx